# In orgmode ASCII export, omit blank lines between items in list

Tags: org-mode

Consider the following:

```
#+OPTIONS: num:nil toc:nil
#+AUTHOR: 

* h1
** h2
*** h3
**** item 1
**** item 2
**** item 3
```

When using ASCII export, orgmode renders that as:

```
h1
==

h2
~~

h3
--

* item 1


* item 2


* item 3
```

I don't like all of the blank lines (or empty lines, or newlines) between the itemized list items. I would prefer it to render as:

```
h1
==

h2
~~

h3
--

* item 1
* item 2
* item 3
```

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way is to customize `org-ascii-headline-spacing`  and set it to nil. That will make the spacing of the output mirror the spacing of the input, so you can set it exactly as you want

The doc string of `org-ascii-headline-spacing` says:

> Number of blank lines inserted around headlines.
>
> This variable can be set to a cons cell.  In that case, its car
>   represents the number of blank lines present before headline
>   contents whereas its cdr reflects the number of blank lines after
>   contents.
>
> A nil value replicates the number of blank lines found in the
>   original Org buffer at the same place.

Comment: Thanks but in my example, this removes the whitespace around h1, h2, h3 also. Setting org-ascii-headline-spacing to (0 . 1) works pretty well though.

Comment: As I said, nil mirrors the whitespace in the input to the output. So you can control it exactly by changing the whitespace in the input file, which I prefer.. But if you are happy with the automatic spacing that (0 . 1) gives you, I'm not going to argue :-)